# OrientDB slow traversal after depth 4

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB is slow after the traversal is greater than depth 3. (depth 3 took 4 seconds, depth 4 took 11, depth 5 took 37 seconds)

My query is: TRAVERSE * FROM (select from products where pid = '73') while $depth<=5

Products extends from V and I have an index type UNIQUE (field pid) with engine SBTree.
When I try with depth 1 until 3 works fine.
I compared with Neo4j and took 3 seconds in depth 5 with the same data.
I am working with OrientDB 2.1.5
Please help me to improve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
TRAVERSE * FROM (select from products where pid = '73') maxdepth 5
```

How many records do you have at 4th and 5th level?

Comment: Yes, it is better now. What is the difference between while $depth<=5 and maxdepth 5?

Comment: What's the new timing now? `maxdepth 5` stops at 5th level, while using the  condition `$depth<=5` the traversal engine must arrive to the depth 6 (fetching more records) to return false.